# Problem of applying concept of hcf

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I know what hcf means way back from my school days.But was recently going through some practice problems for an exam and found problems in applying hcf,like this question:
What is the greatest length of the tape to measure two eq triangles of side 34 and 85 respectively?

I am having difficulty figuring out on why should we find the hcf here.How to clear this confusion and get a clear thought process regarding these problems?

Answer (score 1):

The length of the tape must be a factor of $85$ and $34$, in order to be able to measure the sides with it. It is understood that the tape has no marks on it (that is, it is just a tape, not a measuring tape).

Since we are being asked for the longest possible tape, that common factor must be as highest as possible. This is exactly what Highest Common Factor means.

Answer (score 1):

First thing to note is that this is not a really practical question in the sense that the measuring tape has no markings, all we know about the tape is its total length(say $L$). It is clear that we can only measure distances that are multiples of $L$ using such a tape.

Now you have been given 2 lengths (say $l_1,l_2$) and have to find the largest possible length of the tape that can be used to measure $l_1,l_2$. In order to be able to measure them, both $l_1$ and $l_2$ must be a multiple of $L$. Putting it the other way, $L$ should be a factor of both $l_1$ and $l_2$ i.e., a common factor. And the question asks for the largest possible such $L$. So find the Highest Common Factor.